# Specifying a default port in a Procfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, procfile

I am using `foreman` to start a bunch of services, and have the following line in the Procfile.

```
web:    bundle exec rails server -p ${PORT:-3000}
```

yet when the server starts it starts on the default Foreman port of `5000`, so it looks like the syntax for injecting `3000` as the default port is wrong.

I went looking (someone else gave me the line above so I'd like to fix it) and could not actually find any specific documentation on how to inject a default value.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/master/lib/foreman/process.rb#L34) you see

```
def expanded_command(custom_env={})
  env = @options[:env].merge(custom_env)
  expanded_command = command.dup
  env.each do |key, val|
    expanded_command.gsub!("$#{key}", val)
  end
  expanded_command
end
```

so it's clear that the `${PORT:-3000}` syntax is wrong.

What is the correct way to set a default port?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `Procfile` definition to point to a custom script file:

```
bundle exec ./script/server
```

Then, create the `script/server` file and configure the defaults

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")/.."
[ $PORT ] || PORT=3000

cmd="bundle exec rails server -p $PORT"
exec $cmd
```

Otherwise, simply run `Foreman` passing the port

```
$ foreman start -p 3000
```

Comment: thankyou, that almost worked except that Foreman appears to set `PORT` to `5000` before that script is invoked, so `PORT=3000` was never being invoked. I've opted for modifying the `setup` rake task to provide the default port.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `.env` file with the following content: `PORT=3000`, then in your `Procfile` use `web: bundle exec rails s -p $PORT`

More info here: https://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#ENVIRONMENT

Comment: also correct — thanks, alas SP only lets me count one answer as correct, and @simone-carletti got in first.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on @PJSCopeland answer so I'm adding this as another answer. Foreman isn't Bash but command is written correctly (at the end foreman executes `Process.spawn` with specified command). The problem here is that foreman sets variable `PORT` internally so default `PORT` value 3000 isn't used as it is already defined.

I think that @Kote answer is the best but another way to accomplish this task is to change `PORT` variable name, e.g. to `SERVER_PORT`

```
web:    bundle exec rails server -p ${SERVER_PORT:-3000}
```

Then to change default `SERVER_PORT` execute:

```
SERVER_PORT=3100 foreman start
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreman isn't Bash; you can't interpolate expressions like that.

You could do it like this:

```
export PORT=3000 # only once; this is persistent
foreman run
```

or like this:

```
PORT=3000 foreman run # $PORT is not persistent this way
```

You could extend the former to put the `export` command into an `.*rc` file (such as `.rvmrc`) that loads automatically when you switch to this directory.

Or, you could save the latter as a script and run that instead (as [Simone Carletti suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35004389/1157242)). This is my preferred option.

(I also add `./bin` and `~/bin` to my `PATH`, and put a default script such as `rails s` into the latter under the same name. Then I don't have to remember the "start server" command for each project.)